# Trying to get nfc to work with BCM5880

Tags: 16.04, nfc

I am trying to use my Dell Latitude E6420 nfc reader to read a Mifare classic 1k in a virtualized Ubuntu 16.04. The nfc reader that I have is a build-in BCM5880.

lsusb output

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5801 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor
```

However nfc-list reports no NFC device found and on a side note, fpriontd-enroll also reports that no devices can be found.

How can I get it to work. The reader does work in Windows.

Comment: BCM5880 is a SmartCard/Fingerprint reader. Although NFC is built on the same basic communications technology that Contactless ICC Cards use, it's not the same. Mifare is the latter. A VM probably has no access to that hardware anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The reader is detected in the vm like seen in my question. It also works and reads mifare cards in Windows. But I need it in Ubuntu for Linux only Mifare tools. I will try to install Ubuntu on my laptop and try it that way.

Comment: I've also seen this: https://plus.google.com/+LudovicGasc/posts/4c9jkunwo76